# Filter API response with Angular HTTP?

Tags: angular

I need a filter where I need to make $http call and then return that response . I use filter function to get the only painter name that I want. When I console log the variable that handle the filter it show an error booking.filter is not a function

I have the following code in my Angular service:

```
export class HistoryComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  bookings: any = [];
  jobs: any = [];
  s: any = [];
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getlist();
  }
  getlist() {
    const body = {
      opcode: 'order_list',
      size: 20,
      page: 1,
      sign: 'e5111c807c49a330399ab4ca36a27162',
    };
    this.http
      .post<any>('http://api.1shikj.com/cgi-bin/operate', body)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.bookings = data.data.data;
        for (let booking of  this.bookings) {
          var user_username = localStorage.getItem('user_username');
          // this.jobs = booking.filter(f => !brr.includes(f));
          this.jobs = booking.filter((t) => t.painter_name === user_username);
          console.log(booking);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

my data.data.data return

```
0:
finished_time: null,
goodsid: 471,
goodsprice: "9.50",
id: 5,
optionname: "",
order_id: 66,
orderid: 66,
painter_name: "displayTest",
painter_phone: "1111339039",
price: "9.50",
receiving_time: 1641362420,
service_address: "guangdonggaungzhoupanyudaxuecheng",
service_endtime: 1639374600,
service_name: "Mr.zhu",
service_phone: "15889982165",
service_starttime: 1639367400,
status: "receiving"
thumb: "http://pq.1shikj.com/attachment/images/1/2021/10/ZgMmc9zJmZc4p7AP47UMp474Q7T9An.png"
title: "Samurai Spray Paint HDB Blue 34 (400ml)"
total: 1
uniacid: 1
working_time: null

1:
finished_time: null
goodsid: 471
goodsprice: "9.50"
id: 4
optionname: ""
order_id: 65
orderid: 65
painter_name: "displayTest"
painter_phone: "1111339039"
price: "9.50"
receiving_time: 1641366901
service_address: "guangdonggaungzhoupanyudaxuecheng"
service_endtime: 1639283760
service_name: "Mr.zhu"
service_phone: "15889982165"
service_starttime: 1639276560
status: "receiving"
thumb: "http://pq.1shikj.com/attachment/images/1/2021/10/ZgMmc9zJmZc4p7AP47UMp474Q7T9An.png"
title: "Samurai Spray Paint HDB Blue 34 (400ml)"
total: 1
uniacid: 1

2:
finished_time: null
goodsid: 471
goodsprice: "9.50"
id: 3
optionname: ""
order_id: 64
orderid: 64
painter_name: null
painter_phone: null
price: "9.50"
receiving_time: null
service_address: "guangdonggaungzhoupanyudaxuecheng"
service_endtime: 1639283760
service_name: "Mr.zhu"
service_phone: "15889982165"
service_starttime: 1639276560
status: "paid"
thumb: "http://pq.1shikj.com/attachment/images/1/2021/10/ZgMmc9zJmZc4p7AP47UMp474Q7T9An.png"
title: "Samurai Spray Paint HDB Blue 34 (400ml)"
total: 1
uniacid: 1
working_time: null

3:
finished_time: null
goodsid: 471
goodsprice: "9.50"
id: 2
optionname: ""
order_id: 63
orderid: 63
painter_name: null
painter_phone: null
price: "9.50"
receiving_time: null
service_address: "guangdonggaungzhoupanyudaxuecheng"
service_endtime: 1639283760
service_name: "Mr.zhu"
service_phone: "15889982165"
service_starttime: 1639276560
status: "submit"
thumb: "http://pq.1shikj.com/attachment/images/1/2021/10/ZgMmc9zJmZc4p7AP47UMp474Q7T9An.png"
title: "Samurai Spray Paint HDB Blue 34 (400ml)"
total: 1
uniacid: 1
working_time: null

4:
finished_time: 1638245082
goodsid: 8
goodsprice: "365.00"
id: 1
optionname: "2XL+蓝色"
order_id: 20
orderid: 20
painter_name: "make"
painter_phone: "565661"
price: "365.00"
receiving_time: 1637652466
service_address: "ers"
service_endtime: 1637577000
service_name: "dd"
service_phone: "346211"
service_starttime: 1637566200
status: "finished"
thumb: "http://pq.1shikj.com/attachment/images/1/2021/01/X1RaDz3Z0B0Mo330gA0gdBglymavaAba.jpg"
title: "毛呢大衣男短款2020新款潮流风衣男士加绒加厚修身西装呢子外套"
total: 1
uniacid: 0
working_time: 1637654312
```

Comment: pls share your response. `data.data.data` is this correct ?

Comment: do you want data.data.data responnse ?

Comment: Yes, just need to see `data.data.data`, then only I can tell, why `filter` is breaking

Comment: I share my data.data.data response

Answer (score 0):

booking is not an Array that is why happens that error, try to log it before calling filter method on it or just comment this line too

// this.jobs = booking.filter((t) => t.painter_name === user_username);

and see what actually is booking

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).